# Gabriel's horn about the y-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm trying to figure out if there is a solution to finding the volume of the shape that is formed by rotating $f(x) = \frac 1x$ about the y-axis. Not the x-axis as in Gabriel's horn, but the same problem about the y-axis on the interval $x \ge 1$.

Using the shell method and improper integrals, I end up with $\pi$($\infty$ - 1) where b $\to \infty$.

Is the volume on this infinite? If so, what is the correct way to prove that it is infinite?

Comment: Without the rotation, the area under the curve is infinite. How could it generate a finite volume ?

Comment: The volume when it is rotated about the x-axis approaches a finite value according to Gabriel's horn, but an infinite surface area. I was thinking rotation about the y-axis would produce an infinite volume but I wasn't sure..couldn't find any info on it.

Comment: You are right, I spoke too quickly. Anyway, the volume is given by the integral of 2.Pi.X.1/X.dX  (surface of a cylinder or radius X and height 1/X) from 1 to infinity, which clearly diverges.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't consider that it diverged.

Answer (score 1):

Using the disc (washer) method, the integral to set up is $\int_0^1 \pi (x^2 -1) \; dy$ and you need to recall that $y = \frac{1}{x}$, so $x = \frac{1}{y}$. This integral is improper as the lower limit of integration is not in the domain of the integrand.